# Pandoc problem with Azure Pipelines badge in markdown file

Tags: r, azure-devops, markdown, azure-pipelines, pandoc

Background: I have a number of repos on GitHub, which I've recently converted from using Travis to Azure Pipelines for CI/CD. Azure provides a badge that I can put in a repo's `README.md` to indicate the status of a build. So far, it all works fine, and the badge renders correctly on GitHub.

I've just discovered a problem when I try to convert the README to HTML using pandoc though. For some reason, it turns the badge into an `<embed>` tag rather than `<img>`, and browsers choke on this. This is important because the repos are R packages, and when I submit them to CRAN, the README is converted to HTML using pandoc.

Here's a minimal example. I have 3 badges:

- The CRAN package version
- The Azure Pipelines badge
- A similar Travis badge

```
# Test file

[![CRAN](https://www.r-pkg.org/badges/version/AzureVM)](https://cran.r-project.org/package=AzureVM)
[![Build Status](https://asiadatascience.visualstudio.com/AzureR/_apis/build/status/Azure.AzureVM?branchName=master)](https://asiadatascience.visualstudio.com/AzureR/_build/latest?definitionId=7&branchName=master)
[![Travis Build Status](https://travis-ci.org/cloudyr/AzureRMR.svg?branch=master)](https://travis-ci.org/cloudyr/AzureRMR)
```

If I run `pandoc test.md --from markdown --output test.html`, the result is the following. If I open this file in Edge or Chrome, the Azure badge fails to appear.

```html
<h1 id="test-file">Test file</h1>
<p>
<a href="https://cran.r-project.org/package=AzureVM">
  <img src="https://www.r-pkg.org/badges/version/AzureVM" alt="CRAN" /></a>
<a href="https://asiadatascience.visualstudio.com/AzureR/_build/latest?definitionId=7&amp;branchName=master">
  <embed src="https://asiadatascience.visualstudio.com/AzureR/_apis/build/status/Azure.AzureVM?branchName=master" /></a>
<a href="https://travis-ci.org/cloudyr/AzureRMR">
  <img src="https://travis-ci.org/cloudyr/AzureRMR.svg?branch=master" alt="Travis Build Status" /></a>
</p>
```

[image]

Is this something due to Azure Pipelines or Pandoc? The Azure DevOps project is public, so there shouldn't be any problems accessing it. And how do I fix this?

Comment: Do you HAVE TO pandoc the readme.md? If it's just a matter of passing the CRAN check, you could just add it to your `.Rbuildignore`?

Comment: To be clear: the packages are already on CRAN. CRAN doesn't check that the badge renders correctly, it only cares if pandoc reports an error (which it doesn't). I'm not going to omit the README either, it's an integral part of the documentation.

Comment: Example: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AzureAuth/readme/README.html, compare with https://github.com/Azure/AzureAuth

Comment: I was inspecting the element and the error provided was a 404. More details `Refused to display 'https://asiadatascience.visualstudio.com/AzureR/_apis/build/status/Azure.AzureAuth?branchName=master' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`. I have no idea what that means, but I'd bet it's an Azure problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple things at play here.

1. Chrome refusing to render this is caused by the `X-Frame-Options` header set to `sameorigin` in the HTTP response when fetching the image. Opening the console and viewing the page's errors shows

   > Refused to display 'https://asiadatascience.visualstudio.com/AzureR/_apis/build/status/Azure.AzureAuth?branchName=master' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

   The image will therefore not be rendered when embedded in a document on a different domain. See [RFC7034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7034) for details.
2. The second problem is that pandoc uses `<embed>` instead of `<img>`. This has been resolved in pandoc 2.7.3. From the changelog:

   > HTML writer:
   >
   > - Output video and audio elements depending on file
   >   extension of the image path (Mauro Bieg).

So you can either try to get the `X-Frame-Options` header removed from the build-status HTTP response, or ask the CRAN admins to update to pandoc 2.7.3.

A third option might be to use HTML to include the badge:

```
<a href="https://asiadatascience.visualstudio.com/AzureR/_apis/build/status/Azure.AzureVM?branchName=master"><img src="https://asiadatascience.visualstudio.com/AzureR/_build/latest?definitionId=7&branchName=master" /></a>
```

Including HTML in Markdown is perfectly ok, and it will render fine on both GitHub and when processed with pandoc. The downside is that the badge will not show up when exporting to, say, PDF. But having a badge like this statically included in a PDF may defy its purpose anyway, so this is should be a good solution.

Comment: Both of those look like extremely terrifying options! But thanks

Comment: @HongOoi Just thought of a third approach, it's probably the easiest.